# Is it possible to launch applications in compatibility mode through Rocket Dock?

Tags: rocketdock

I can't find such an option in "icon settings"

Comment: Consider adding some more information to your question -- such as OS version.

Comment: Compatability at least in XP seems to be set on the Program itself in the registry, even though it seems like your tagging a shortcut. **THE USERS KEY\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\** Try and test that, set it on the executable itself , then test it from your launcher.

Comment: Thank you so much! All you have to do is right click on the executable itself. Can't believe I didn't try this before

Answer (score 2):

If you *always* want to run the app in compatibility mode, you can select it in the start menu or explorer, right click > properties, then go to the compatibility tab and choose "run this program in compatibility mode."

The menu looks like this:

[image: Compatibility Mode]